# Alternative to Subtle Patterns plugin?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, plugin

Source Academy has discontinued their Subtle Patterns Photoshop plugin (and all their other plugins), and I'm left without a tool I use frequently.  Any suggestions for an alternative plugin for subtle background patterns and textures?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Could you post examples of the kind of patterns you are talking about. I'm not familiar with the plugin or what it was used for.

Comment: The plugin pulled patterns from https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns for use as pattern overlays directly in Photoshop.  I can still get the patterns from the website, but the plugin made it much easier.

Comment: If the patterns are downloadable, you could convert them to a pattern set that you can save in Photoshop for future use. There's a [tutorial here](https://www.lifewire.com/add-save-custom-patterns-as-set-1700239)

Comment: Sure.  It's just a tedious process.  The plugin did all the work.  Thanks.